# Dropdown not working ,using Ts in react-native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dropdown, react-native-dropdown-picker

I made custom dropdown component using model and flatlist.but its showing error(Property 'label' does not exist on type 'never') and its not working properly.
component code below here is whole block for that componenet part

```
 interface Props {
  label: string;
  data: Array<{label: string; value: string}>;
  onSelect: (item: {label: string; value: string}) => void;
  selected?: undefined;
}

const Dropdown: FC<Props> = ({label, data, onSelect}: any) => {
  const DropdownButton = React.useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<any>;
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(undefined);
  const [dropdownTop, setDropdownTop] = useState(0);

  const toggleDropdown = (): void => {
    visible ? setVisible(false) : openDropdown();
  };

  const openDropdown = (): void => {
    DropdownButton.current.measure(
      (_fx: any, _fy: any, _w: any, h: any, _px: any, py: any) => {
        setDropdownTop(py + h);
      },
    );
    setVisible(true);
  };

  const onItemPress = ({item}: any): void => {
    setSelected(item);
    onSelect(item);
    setVisible(false);
  };

  const renderItem = ({item}: any): ReactElement<any, any> => (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => onItemPress(item)}>
      <Text>{item.label}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  const renderDropdown = (): ReactElement<any, any> => {
    return (
      <Modal visible={visible} transparent animationType="none">
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.overlay}
          onPress={() => setVisible(false)}>
          <View style={[styles.dropdown, {top: dropdownTop}]}>
            <FlatList
              data={data}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Modal>
    );
  };
 return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      ref={DropdownButton}
      style={styles.button}
      onPress={toggleDropdown}>
      {renderDropdown()}
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
        {(selected && selected.label) || label}
      </Text>
      <Icon
        style={styles.icon}
        type="font-awesome"
        name="chevron-down"
        tvParallaxProperties={undefined}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

and its usage below :-

```
 const [selected, setSelected] = useState(undefined);
  const data = [
    {label: 'One', value: '1'},
    {label: 'Two', value: '2'},
    {label: 'Three', value: '3'},
    {label: 'Four', value: '4'},
    {label: 'Five', value: '5'},
  ];

  return <Dropdown label="Select Item" data={data} onSelect={setSelected} />;
```

main error:- after clicking value in dropdown its not showing as selected.

Comment: Move the contents of the `renderDropdown` function into the function above it. That function never gets called, but the code doesn't really belong in a function anyway.

Comment: did not under stand

Comment: You changed your code so my comment no longer makes sense.

Comment: sorry to inform you but previous code was incomplete so I made chnages